# IF statement causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

The IF statement below causes a 500 error.  The page loads fine when I remove the IF statement.

If there anything wrong with it?

```
$oldtweets = mysql_query("SELECT submissionid, loginid FROM tweets WHERE submissionid = '$submissionid' AND loginid = '$loginid'");

if (mysql_num_rows($oldtweets) = 0)
{
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (NULL, '$city', '$submissionid', '$fullurl', '$uid', '$username', NULL)");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `if (mysql_num_rows($oldtweets) == 0)` with a double "=" to use a comparison operator instead of an assignment operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would look at is this -

```
if (mysql_num_rows($oldtweets) = 0)
```

Should be this -

```
if (mysql_num_rows($oldtweets) == 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using a single `=`, which is the assignment operator. You should be using `==`, the comparison operator.